# How to add seconds(can go upto 10E12) to a datetime variable in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am a newbie in python and I need to add a variable which has seconds in it to a datetime variable.

The variable which has the seconds stored and the date to which it should be added looks like this. But couldnt get it correct as timedelta has only upto days.

```
sec_var = 1.83920792079208E+04
print st_ti
2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Note: The sec_var can go upto 10(pow)12 which means I need to take care till years.

So basically I need the seconds value to get added to the date variable. Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I did a big mistake 10e12 seconds is really very long, about 30000 years. I do not think that `datetime` module datatypes can process such values.

But if you need no more than several thousand years, just use `datetime` and `timedelta`:

```
initial = datetime.datetime(2013,1,1)
print initial
# => 2013-01-01 00:00:00
dat = initial + datetime.timedelta(seconds = 1.83920792079208E+011)
print dat
# => 7841-03-21 20:54:39.208008
```

But I must ackowledge that above breaks at 1.8e12 after that you run into the Y10k problem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_10,000_problem

Comment: Thanks. It is enough for a + or - 100 years. So it should be fine